# Do we have to explicitly add to db context?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

```
public class Practice
{
    public List<Participation> Participation { get; set; }
}

public class Participation
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Practice Practice { get; set; }
}

public void test()
{
    var practice = _ctx.Practice.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == practiceId);
    practice.Participations.AddRange(NewParticipations);
    _ctx.Participation.AddRange(NewParticipations)
    await _ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

If I have the above, would I need the 3rd line in the test function to save new participations or would the practice.Participations.AddRange() handle that implicitly?

Comment: It will do it implicitly. Read this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/related-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`practice.Participations.AddRange` should be enough.

> If you reference a new entity from the navigation property of an entity that is already tracked by the context, the entity will be discovered and inserted into the database.

source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/related-data#adding-a-related-entity

You can observe it like so...

```
var practice = _ctx.Practice.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Id == practiceId);

practice.Participations.AddRange(NewParticipations);

Debug.WriteLine(_ctx.Participation.Count()); //note count

await _ctx.SaveChangesAsync();

Debug.WriteLine(_ctx.Participation.Count()); //count increased
```

Comment: Would I have to do _ctx.Practice.Update(practice) before the SaveChangesAsync for it to be tracked?

Comment: No, you don't have to. All entities queried from the `DbContext` will be automatically tracked. (...assuming you did not change the tracking behavior)

Comment: Ah okay. So if I created a new participation, and then did
newParticipation.Practice = practice. Where practice is the tracked practice from DbContext, the SaveChanges won't catch it since participation is new at this time and have not yet been added to the context? But if I did practice.Particiations.Add(newParticipation) it would see the change.

Comment: Yes, since `practice` is tracked by the `DbContext`.

Comment: If the participations are only added on localhost but not on stage (hosted on azure), would this be an issue with the db tracking still?

Comment: I believe that's out of scope of the original question as well as EF. Try continuing your work from here and post another question if you get into an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add the new data to the database either way. If you added through the context, you would need to set the foreign key in the NewParticipations objects yourself, so that a link would exist to the Practice object.